# Rendering MediaCodec Decoded Data in Opengl Surface

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I am currently working on Android Application in Java. I need to stream H.264 format on OpenGL Surface. To continuously decode the buffers using MediaCodec, I called a function which continuously gives the Videoframes data in OnDrawFrame() and decoded the buffers using MediaCodec .The buffers which I am receiving are correct and the decoding is happening perfectly. To stream the video the decoded frames need to be renderer in the surface.

Can anyone tell me how to renderer the decoded frames of MediaCodec in OpenGL Surface for video Streaming.